# Prevent chrome extensions from using network

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is there a way to permanently prevent any offline Chrome-extensions/Chrome-Apps from using network?

Apparently, toggling this **Offline** button does it temporarily.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like [site access UI](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769) on chrome://extensions page. If not, please elaborate on "offline app/extension".

Comment: @wOxxOm "offline app/extension" works both offline and online. Their primary usage is offline but they make network call for some verification idk

Comment: Well, there's no such term but I think what I suggested should work - just add a dummy nonexistent site in the list of permitted sites.